# TYPO3 indexed_search does not index the page

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

In my TYPO3 6.2.31 page I try to get indexed_search working.

In Backend it looks good, Search Page form is implemented as well.

Problem is the page will not get indexed.

Any ideas?

**Update**

in template I have this:

```
<!--  main content anfang  -->
<main role="main" class="maininhalt">
<!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->
###CONTENTMAIN###
<!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->
</main>
<!--  main content ende  -->
```

and in typoscript setup:

```
page.config.index_enable = 1
```

Comment: just a couple of checks:
1) do you use crawler or you enabled the automatic frontend indexing in the extension configuration?
2) your templates contain <!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin--> .... <!--TYPO3SEARCH_end--> ?

Comment: no i do nt use crawler. and yes I have the markers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some Teamviewer investigations we found the problem:

It was caused by the language configuration in the system. The system only had **one** language but was configured as the following:

```
config {
  sys_language_uid = 1 // Instead of "0" if there is only one language
  sys_language_mode = content_fallback
  sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
}
```

Somehow this caused the indexed_search to not index the content. **After removing `sys_language_mode` and `sys_language_overlay` the indexing worked as expected.**

Comment: Thanks for your help and time Paul!

Answer (score 3):

Index is filled only if cache is filled.
As long as you are logged in in BE all calls to FE are uncached.
Either use a crawler to get your complete site indexed or use another browser to fill the cache/ index.

Is your content / are your pages in general cachable?

Other possibility for missing index: is the configuration ok?
have you set?

```
config.index_enable = 1
```

or

```
page.config.index_enable = 1
```

Have you included the markers which control indexing and used correctly?
The markers are `<!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->` and `<!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->`.
If you don't use it the complete page is indexed.

Is there anything indexed (you may search for non indexed words)?
Look into the info module to see whether there are pages with indexed content.

---

You may have a look into the manual:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/indexed_search/

Comment: I call the frontend from another computer. Is cache still disabled then as well?

I think the page is cachable? how can I test it?

Yes I have set it in typoscript setup

yes the markers are added as well.

No nothing is indexed. all are not indexed

Comment: you did not `Disable frontend-initiated indexing` accidently? https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/indexed_search/7.6/IndexingConfigurations/DisableFrontendIndexing/Index.html

Comment: should the checkbox be checked or not?

Comment: at the moment its not checked

Comment: any other hints?

Comment: it should be not checked so you can fill the index by visiting a page. check with admin-tool whether cache-entries are generated. more info about caching can be found at [this german page](http://typo3blog.at/blog/artikel/typo3-caching-grundlagen/). Do you have extensions which disable cache? have you cache disabled in TS?

Comment: no cahe is not disabled, and no extension disables it. I've double checked this

Comment: Wilke any tips for caching problem?

Comment: caching is sovled. pages are cached now. but indexing does not work at all

Comment: @Felix: In case of emergency you can contact me on Skype at "hi@toll-paul.de" and I can check your system with Teamviewer. When we've found the mistake we will post the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

In your other topic regarding the caching problem I've seen inside the adminPanel that you've got some Frontend-User-(Group)s. [typo3 does not cache the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094965/typo3-does-not-cache-the-page)

As mentioned by Bernd: Please try to open your site in some kind of inkognito-mode of your browser **without** logging in to the TYPO3 backend and without beeing logged in as Frontend-User. After that check if your index has been updated.

Comment: also tried in incognito and not logged in ... nothing changed