# TYPO3 does not cache the page

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

My TYPO3 6.2.31 page has everywhere enabled caching ... But when I call the Page and look in admin panel ..

[image]

[image]

My typoscript looks like this:

```
config {
doctype = html5 
renderCharset = utf-8
metaCharset = utf-8
prefixLocalAnchors = all
simulateStaticDocuments = 0
tx_realurl_enable = 1
absRefPrefix = /  
  #CACHE AND INDEX
no_cache = 0
no_search = 0
index_enable = 1
index_externals = 1
```

what could be the problem for not caching my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prefixLocalAnchors causes the page to be not cached!
Set `prefixLocalAnchors = 0`

Comment: Thanks that was the problem, and what does prefixLocalAnchors do?

Comment: do you maybe have a hint for me in this case as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090238/typo3-indexed-search-does-not-index-the-page Thought when caching works fine, indexing as well ... but not

Comment: I don't get it: how can `prefixLocalAnchors` be the culprit? if I look at the [sources](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/7/html/_typo_script_frontend_controller_8php_source.html#l04149) the cache is disabled only if a BE user is logged in. But then we expect no caching.

Comment: I already did not really understand it but stopped thinking about it since prefixLocalAnchors has been removed in TYPO3 8 LTS

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things which incluence if a page is cached or not:

- an extension
- TS like page.config.no_cache = 1
- disable caching in the page properties

and I guess some more as well.

Comment: - I can't find any ts with no_cache=1 
- page properties would be for one page right? ... but no page is cached... 
- how can I check the extensions?